# Scrapy starts redirecting to captcha after some requests

Tags: python, scrapy

I am crawling Glassdoor list of jobs in USA. After making some requests to the job pages it redirects me to the captcha. 
I have also tried rotating proxy with every request and User-Agent as well.

Comment: This is kind of expected. Big sites have protection against scraping their info -- captcha is one of them.

Comment: Anyway to overcome that. i also tried crawling this site using crawlera which rotate the IP of the request from a pool of IP's.

Comment: and why dont use the API?
https://www.glassdoor.com/developer/jobsApiActions.htm

Comment: Not the solution im looking for.

Comment: @VickyButt this out of this site's scope, that's why your question is likely to be closed

Comment: You can use something to solve the captcha like deathbycaptcha service.